# Sending an email to an email GROUP in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, email, plsql, smtp

I'm trying to send an email to email addresses in a mailing group with the package and procedure below.

```
xxfr_mail_package.begin_mail (  sender       => '<MEKSICO-IYE<noreply@meksico.com>',
                                recipients   => fnd_profile.value('XXPC_PLANNING_MAIL'), 
                                subject      => l_subject,
                                mime_type    => 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-9',
                                priority     => '',                                     
                                cc           => l_cc );
```

**fnd_profile.value('XXPC_PLANNING_MAIL')** returns email addresses separated by semicolons. In this case, sending emails to each address is seamless.
However, when a group e-mail is given as an argument to the recipients parameter, no e-mail is sent to the e-mail addresses in the group. Since the list of recipients is long, I want to use an email group as an argument.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Where is that "group" defined ?

Comment: All I know is that it's not in the same Oracle environment.

Comment: Oracle doesn't validate individual e-mail addresses. It has no way to know if any particular address is for an individual or a group. Do you know that Oracle isn't sending the message, or only that the message isn't being received? Could it be getting blocked by the e-mail server because the sender address doesn't have permissions to send to the group? Is there an error message being generated?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved by removing restriction on the distribution list on the Exchange Server side. Thanks for your valuable responses. [image: details are in the picture]